# Filter behavior of Richfaces rich:select

Tags: jsf, richfaces

When I use a `rich:select` with `enableManualInput="true"`, I can filter the values of the select box by typing the first character of the list of options and select an option. However, when I again click on the select box, it shows only the selected option and all other unselected options are not displayed. This is quite different from the behavior of a normal select box.  Is there any attribute associated with `rich:select` where I can change this default behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bug in RichFaces: https://issues.jboss.org/browse/RF-11088

But there is a fix available (refer to the pull request):
https://github.com/richfaces/richfaces/pull/40/files